# apt-cache search : command not found

Tags: apt, search, apt-cache

I am using an Amazon EC2 instance with Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS installed.  I am getting "command not found" whenever I try to use "apt-cache search", both with and without "sudo " prefixed :

```
apt-cache search : command not found
apt-cache search libssl: command not found
sudo: apt-cache search libssl: command not found
```

However, when I run "apt-cache" by itself I get the general help output:

```
apt 2.4.8 (amd64)
Usage: apt-cache [options] command
   apt-cache [options] show pkg1 [pkg2 ...]

apt-cache queries and displays available information
... 
  search - Search the package list for a regex pattern
```

Any ideas how I can get this working? TIA

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had copied the code ("apt-cache search libssl") from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenSSL, and it must have contained invisible characters. When I typed the full command in manually, it worked fine.